# hosting Django REST API on subdomain

Tags: nginx, django

So I have this domain `fimetsu.com`, here is my `frontend` hosted on. Now I need to find a way to host my `Django REST API` so my `frontend` can communicate with my `backend`. I was thinking of hosting this on `dev.fimetsu.com` (Not sure what best practices are about this). Now I'm struggling to find out how to create an Nginx sites-available for this. Because they both (fimetsu.com and dev.fimetsu.com) will have the same IP-Address. So if anyone has had experience with this your help is greatly appreciated